# Return entire objects after filtering not just values that match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently filtering an array of objects against an array of values.  My array of objects looks like the following, this array is defined as arr1:

```
[
  {
    "filters": {
      "counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
      "gender": ["Male"],
      "rate": ["$300 or less"],
      "experience": ["10 or fewer"],
      "rating": ["10 or fewer"]
    }
  },
  {
    "filters": {
      "counties": ["Montgomery", "Chester"],
      "gender": ["Male"],
      "rate": ["$301-350"],
      "experience": ["11-20"],
      "rating": ["31+"]
    }
  },

  {
  "filters": {
      "counties": ["Philadelphia"],
      "gender": ["Male"],
      "rate": ["$301-350"],
      "experience": ["11-20"],
      "rating": ["31+"]
    }
  }
]
```

and I am comparing the array of objects to a data structure that looks like the following, this object is defined as obj:

```
{
"counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
"gender": ["Male"],
"experience": ["10 or fewer"],
"rating": ["10 or fewer"]
}
```

I am able to filter the counties by doing the following:

```
    arr1.map((item) => {
      item.filters.counties.filter((i) => {
        if (obj.counties.includes(i)) {
          console.log(item)
          return item
        }
      })
    })
```

the console log successfully returns all objects in arr1 that contain Philadelphia but I am not returning correctly.  I am wondering, the best way to go about stacking these filters one after the other. I am somewhat at a loss currently.  I have created a codesandbox for debugging https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hodgkin-pwlyg?file=/src/index.js

The desired Result: All objects within arr1 are returned that match the map of arrays that it is compared against

Comment: Are you looking to match *any* of the fields or *all* of them?

Comment: Sorry can you explain the difference so I can give you a solid answer

Comment: Basically the idea is all filters do not have to be applied for a result to come back

Comment: Do you want the values that match on counties, gender, experience **and** rating?  Or do you want all the values that match **any** of those criteria?

Comment: Also, please post relevant code in the question.  An external link is fine for extra information, but the question should be self-contained.

Comment: I would like all values that match those criteria to return.  and I have posted the code necessary to answer the question, I worry adding more will only over complicate the thread

Comment: Does the second element of arr1 get included since it does match at least one filter (gender) or do we not include it since it doesn't match every filter (all the others)?  In other words, what is the expected output?

Comment: If it doesn't match gender it should not be included, my apologies for any confusion

Comment: There is still one open question to my mind.  Do we test that every value in the criteria property must be in the object's matching filter property?  Or do we test that every value in the object's property must be in the criteria property?  Or do we test both, that, for instance, `obj.filters.counties` must contain the exact same values as `criteria.counties` (perhaps in a different order?)

Comment: the order the values are in shouldn't matter for the counties  and as long as a single value matches for instance if an array contains philadelphia and bucks but the obj being passed in only has philadelphia.  The array containing both philadelphia and bucks should be returned

Comment: So basically a criteria matches if there is any overlap between it and the object?  I will revisit my answer.

Comment: yes I believe that is the behavior that I am trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$300 or less"],
      experience: ["10 or fewer"],
      rating: ["10 or fewer"]
    }
  },
  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Montgomery", "Chester"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$301-350"],
      experience: ["11-20"],
      rating: ["31+"]
    }
  },

  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Philadelphia"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$301-350"],
      experience: ["11-20"],
      rating: ["31+"]
    }
  }
];


const obj = {
  counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
  gender: ["Male"],
  experience: ["10 or fewer"],
  rating: ["10 or fewer"]
};


let output = [];
arr1.map((item) => {
  return item.filters.counties.filter((i) => {
    if (obj.counties.includes(i)) {
      console.log(item);
      output.push(item);
      return item;
    }
    return null;
  });
});

console.log("-----------------------------------");
console.log(output); // if you need to take retured values
```

You can use an `Array` to collect all the items include in `object.countries`

Comment: If I wanted to stack filters would you go about it by first collecting the counties match then filter against the gender, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only the filters which countries list contains "Philadelphia" or "Bucks", you can reduce the filters. You need to keep only filters that match every constraint, by checking if the constraint includes any (some) of the values for the filter.

```js
const filters = arr1.reduce((acc, item) =>
  Object.entries(obj).every(([key, val]) =>
      val.some(v => item.filters[key].includes(v)))
    ? [...acc, item ] : acc);
```

This could alternatively be used as a filter, rather than a reducer. This allows the item to be destructed (pull out `filters`), since we no longer need to return it.

```js
const filteredFilters = arr1.filter(({ filters }) =>
  Object.entries(obj).every(([key, val]) =>
      val.some(v => filters[key].includes(v))));
```

**Note:** I gave `arr1` (now `globalFilters`) and `obj` (now `criteria`) more descriptive names. It helps figure out what is going on.

```js
const globalFilters = [{
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$300 or less"],
    "experience": ["10 or fewer"],
    "rating": ["10 or fewer"]
  }
}, {
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Montgomery", "Chester"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$301-350"],
    "experience": ["11-20"],
    "rating": ["31+"]
  }
}, {
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Philadelphia"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$301-350"],
    "experience": ["11-20"],
    "rating": ["31+"]
  }
}];

const criteria = {
  "counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
  "gender": ["Male"],
  "experience": ["10 or fewer"],
  "rating": ["10 or fewer"]
};

const filters = globalFilters.reduce((acc, item) =>
  item.filters.counties.find(country => criteria.counties.includes(country))
    ? [...acc, item ] : acc, []);

console.log(filters);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to filter by all criteria you can mix some/every to evaluate the presence of items in an array.

```js
const globalFilters = [{
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$300 or less"],
    "experience": ["10 or fewer"],
    "rating": ["10 or fewer"]
  }
}, {
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Montgomery", "Chester"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$301-350"],
    "experience": ["11-20"],
    "rating": ["31+"]
  }
}, {
  "filters": {
    "counties": ["Philadelphia"],
    "gender": ["Male"],
    "rate": ["$301-350"],
    "experience": ["11-20"],
    "rating": ["31+"]
  }
}];

const criteria = {
  "counties": ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
  "gender": ["Male"],
  "experience": ["10 or fewer"],
  "rating": ["10 or fewer"]
};

const filters = globalFilters.reduce((acc, item) =>
  Object.entries(criteria).every(([key, val]) =>
      val.some(v => item.filters[key].includes(v)))
    ? [...acc, item ] : acc);

console.log(filters);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: in this scenario, how can I go about stacking these filters? say a user is inputting the specific fitlers.  they will maintain the same data format just need to be able to stack them.  PS I am using the top example

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Changing `every` to `some` based on comments.

Something like this might do:

```js
const filterAll = (criteria) => (objects) =>
  objects .filter (({filters}) => Object .entries (criteria) .every (
   ([k, val]) => val .some (v => filters [k] .includes (v))
  ))
  

const arr1 = [{filters: {counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"], gender: ["Male"], rate: ["$300 or less"], experience: ["10 or fewer"], rating: ["10 or fewer"]}}, {filters: {counties: ["Montgomery", "Chester"], gender: ["Male"], rate: ["$301-350"], experience: ["11-20"], rating: ["31+"]}}, {filters: {counties: ["Philadelphia"], gender: ["Male"], rate: ["$301-350"], experience: ["11-20"], rating: ["31+"]}}]
const obj = {counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"], gender: ["Male"], experience: ["10 or fewer"], rating: ["10 or fewer"]}

console .log (filterAll (obj) (arr1))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We filter the objects by looking at *every* property of the criteria object, and then checking if every entry in the target field is included in the filter object.

There is still one guess involved in this answer.

Does object:

```
{filters: {counties: ['A', 'B', 'C'], ...}}
```

match criteria

```
{counties: ['A', 'B'], ...}
```

because every every in the criteria field is included in the object?  Or does it mismatch because there is a value in the object ('C') not included in the criteria?  My assumption is the former, but either would make sense.

### Old code

```js
const filterAll = (criteria) => (objects) =>
  objects .filter (({filters}) => Object .entries (criteria) .every (
   ([k, val]) => val .every (v => filters [k] .includes (v))
  ))
```

Note the change:

```js
   ([k, val]) => val .some (v => filters [k] .includes (v))
   //                 ^^^^
```

Comment: I'm noticing when I attempt to implement this code what happens is only 4 objects from my main array ever get returned.  I'm wondering what could be the cause of this

Comment: Updated to handle what I think are the real requirements.

Comment: in this update, I'm noticing only one object is returned even though one of the objects contains philadelphia

Comment: But the `experience` and `rating` don't match.  I thought you wanted to match *all* the criteria.  I think you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66443463/edit) the question with information about which objects should match and why.

Comment: there is a possibility all filters won't be applied

Comment: I'm done trying to guess.  If you want to update the question with more clear-cut requirements, especially some sample input matched with their expected outputs, then I might try again.  But not until then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting all filter keys and iterate through the array to check whether the particular property contains at least 1 value from the filter's respective array.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$300 or less"],
      experience: ["10 or fewer"],
      rating: ["10 or fewer"]
    }
  },
  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Montgomery", "Chester"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$301-350"],
      experience: ["11-20"],
      rating: ["31+"]
    }
  },

  {
    filters: {
      counties: ["Philadelphia"],
      gender: ["Male"],
      rate: ["$301-350"],
      experience: ["10 or fewer"],
      rating: ["10 or fewer"]
    }
  }
];

const obj = {
  counties: ["Philadelphia", "Bucks"],
  gender: ["Male"],
  experience: ["10 or fewer"],
  rating: ["10 or fewer"]
};

const filterList = Object.keys(obj);
const filtered = arr1.filter((item) => {
  // get an array of respective filter states
  const res = filterList.map((filterName) =>
    // check if item's particular field contains at least 1 value from 'filters' obj.
    obj[filterName].some((el) => item.filters[filterName].includes(el))
  );
  // return only items for whom all filters are 'true'
  return res.every((el) => el);
});
console.log(filtered);
```